# C# Unable to modify Json with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I have a string type variable named `final` and it contains the following Json:

```json
{
  "Game": {
    "Player_Decks": {
      "1": {
        "Card_List": "2_Yellow,1_Blue,Reverse_Green,5_Yellow,5_Red,7_Red,2_Blue",
        "Card_Count": 7
      },
      "2": {
        "Card_List": "5_Blue,9_Green,4_Yellow,6_Green,0_Red,2_Green,6_Yellow",
        "Card_Count": 7
      }
    },
    "Deck_NoCards": {}
  }
}
```

My code looks like this: (taken from here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)

```cs
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(final);
JObject channel = (JObject)rss["Game.Player_Decks.1"];

channel.Property("Card_Count").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new", "New value"));
```

I want to add another value after Card_Count, but I have a feeling that my string isn't "compatible" or something. What can be done here to fix my problem?

Comment: I don't think access through "Game.Player_Decks.1" works. I tried it for myself and it worked fine by doing `JObject game = (JObject)rss["Game"]; JObject decks = (JObject)game["Player_Decks"]; JObject deck1 = (JObject)decks["1"]; deck1.Property("Card_Count").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new", "New value"));` Also, maybe you want to use a Json Array instead of properties named 1, 2, etc.?

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting comment as answer here:

You cannot access the nested object using a *dotted path* "Game.Player_Decks.1". Instead you need to individually address each property within each object.

> JObjects are effectively an array of named properties, `JObject` implements `IDictionary<string, JToken?>` so as long as each child element is also a JObject  then you can use the string index to reference the element in the next level.

```cs
JObject game = (JObject)rss["Game"];
JObject decks = (JObject)game["Player_Decks"];
JObject channel = (JObject)decks["1"];
channel.Property("Card_Count").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new", "New value"));
```

The following syntax should also work:

```cs
JObject channel = rss["Game"]["Player_Decks"]["1"] as JObject;
```

---

Also, have you considered using a Json Array instead of properties named 1, 2, etc. like so:

```json
{
    "Game": {
        "Player_Decks": [
            {
                "Card_List": "2_Yellow,1_Blue,Reverse_Green,5_Yellow,5_Red,7_Red,2_Blue",
                "Card_Count": 7
            },
            {
                "Card_List": "5_Blue,9_Green,4_Yellow,6_Green,0_Red,2_Green,6_Yellow",
                "Card_Count": 7
            }
        ],
        "Deck_NoCards": {}
    }
}
```

and accessed as:

```cs
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(final);
JObject game = (JObject)rss["Game"];
JArray decks = (JArray)game["Player_Decks"];
JObject deck1 = (JObject)decks[0];
```